# svn:externals command for changing a property

Tags: svn

I am pulling some of my code into a folder through svn externals. I know how to see the svn externals using "svn pget" command but not sure how to change the tag dependency from  2.0.0-b-21 to 2.0.0-b-22. How can I do it through SVN command? I know how to do it through Windows TortoiseSVN but not through Unix.

`secdevapp03.gspt.net $ svn pget svn:externals
http://devsvn.gspt.net/svn/components/store-analytics/myapp-analytics-rules/tags/2.0.0-b-21/src/main/resources/analyticsPlatform/myapp src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/analytics-platform-rules/myapp`

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says :

> In addition to the propset command,
>   the svn program supplies the propedit
>   command. This command uses the
>   configured editor program (see the
>   section called “Config”) to add or
>   modify properties. When you run the
>   command, svn invokes your editor
>   program on a temporary file that
>   contains the current value of the
>   property (or which is empty, if you
>   are adding a new property). Then, you
>   just modify that value in your editor
>   program until it represents the new
>   value you wish to store for the
>   property, save the temporary file, and
>   then exit the editor program. If
>   Subversion detects that you've
>   actually changed the existing value of
>   the property, it will accept that as
>   the new property value. If you exit
>   your editor without making any
>   changes, no property modification will
>   occur:

```
svn propedit svn:externals src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/analytics-platform-rules/myapp
```